# std::size_t vs size_t vs std::string::size_type

Tags: c++

- Where does `size_t` come from when I don't have anything included?
- Is it reasonable to always assume `size_t` == `std::size_t`?
- When should I use the `size_type` in `std` containers (`string::size_type`, `vector<T>::size_type`, etc)?

Comment: Sounds like a compiler specific

Comment: Could you explain what you observed for your first point?  For your compiler, does `size_t a;` work as a declaration even when you haven't `#include`d anything?  Since it appears to be a question about an implementation, could you tell us which implementation you're using?

Comment: @DavidThornley That's exactly what I see, I'm using VS2010

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Where does size_t come from when I don't have anything included in an empty project?

If you don't have anything included, then you can't use `size_t`. It's defined in `<stddef.h>` (and perhaps also in `<cstddef>`, if your version of that header puts the definitions in the global namespace as well as `std`).

> Is it reasonable to always assume size_t == std::size_t?

Yes. All types and functions defined by the C library are included in the `std` namespace, as long as you include the appropriate C++ header (e.g. `<cstddef>` rather than `<stddef.h>`)

> When should I use std::**_**::size_type?

Do you mean the `size_type` types defined in some standard classes and templates such as `vector`? You could use those when using those classes if you like. In most cases, you'll know that it's the same as `size_t`, so you might as well use that and save a bit of typing. If you're writing generic code, where you don't know what the class is, then it's better to use `size_type` in case it's not compatible with `size_t`.

For example, you might want to write a container designed to hold more items than can be represented by `size_t`. You might use some kind of big number type to represent the container's size, which isn't convertible to `size_t`. In that case, code like `size_t s = c.size()` would fail to compile - you'd need to use `Container::size_type` instead.

Comment: On your first point, I can use size_t when I haven't included anything. For reference - I'm using VS2010.

Comment: @Dave: That's presumably a Microsoft extension to the language - there are a lot of them. Try compiling with language extensions disabled.

Comment: You're right about what I meant by `std::____::size_type` but can you elaborate on when it could be 'incompatible' with size_t, and the difference between what std::size_t and ::size_type represent?

Comment: @Dave: I've added a bit more detail on that.

Comment: since C++14 a type whose size cannot be represented by std::size_t is ill-formed.

Comment: @user3063349, that is true, but here, the “size of the type” refers to the size of the object, i.e. `sizeof(Type)`, and not the return value of `Type::size()`, which is for a container the number of elements it logically holds, and that may be anything. The elements can be stored in a way that does not require objects with a large `sizeof` – the elements as a whole need not be stored in memory at all, e.g. read from disk or generated on demand.
`std::` containers just happen to limit themselves to `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Where does `size_t` come from when I don't have anything included in an empty project?

`size_t` is a base unsigned integer memsize-type defined in the standard library of C/C++ languages. It is defined in `"stddef.h"` for `C` and in `<cstddef>` for `C++`.

Types defined by the header file `"stddef.h"` are located in the global namespace while `<cstddef>` header places the `size_t` type in the namespace `std`.

`"stddef.h"` from C is included into C++ for compatibility, and hence the type can be found in both the global namespace (`::size_t`) and the `std` namespace (`std::size_t`).

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` and is in `std` namespace.

Comment: It would be good(atleast for me to learn) if the downvoter explains the reason.