# How does Eclipse CDT understand __SIZE_TYPE__?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, codan

When I open the declaration of `size_t` in Eclipse I get to `stddef.h` from GCC with the line:
`typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;`

I understand that `__SIZE_TYPE__` is not defined in any header file, but is known by the compiler.

But, how does Eclipse CDT understand that `__SIZE_TYPE__` and `size_t` are integer types, so it can do code analysis etc? Is it built into CDT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

`__SIZE_TYPE__` can be found at Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Entries -> CDT GCC Built in Compiler Settings, where it says `__SIZE_TYPE__ = unsigned int.`

Looking at the Providers tab, CDT extracts the list from GCC by running `${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD ${INPUTS}`, where `${COMMAND}` is gcc and `${INPUTS}` is an empty C or C++ file.

`-E` preprocess only `-P` no linemarkers `-v` verbose `-dD` Dump all macro definitions.

GCC outputs various internal defines including `#define __SIZE_TYPE__ unsigned int`

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't understand `__SIZE_TYPE__` - that's a GCC thing.  For example:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Layout.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gccint/Driver.html

Here's a more complete explanation:

[Where is c++ size_t defined in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490622/where-is-c-size-t-defined-in-linux)

Comment: Eclipse does not mark `size_t` as unknown type, like it does if I type `foobar x;` without defining the type `foobar`. If I add `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ foobar;` it accepts foobar, which leads me to believe that CDT either know about `__SIZE_TYPE__` or calls GCC in the background.