# Is size_t is always unsigned int

Tags: c++, size-t

Are there any implementations that have `size_t` defined as something else than `unsigned int`? Under every system I worked, it was defined as unsigned int, so I'm just curious.

Comment: I think the idea is that it's not *guaranteed* to be, thus being called `size_t`. It's a type expected by some specific C library calls to define a size argument (for example, the length of a buffer). I wouldn't write code that assumes it's an `unsigned int` even if you've never seen it defined otherwise.

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x86-64 and aarch64 (arm64) Linux, OS X and iOS all have `size_t` ultimately defined as `unsigned long`. (This is the LP64 model. This kind of thing is part of the platform's ABI which also defines things like function calling convention, etc. Other architectures may vary.) Even 32-bit x86 and ARM architectures use `unsigned long` on these OSes, although `long` happens to be the same representation as an `int` in those cases.

I'm fairly sure it's an `unsigned __int64`/`unsigned long long` on Win64. (which uses the LLP64 model)

Answer (score 5):

No. But it is an unsigned *integer* type. It need not be *int* specifically.

### For C++

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

C++ standard secton 18.2.6

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type
>   that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

For linux; "[Where is c++ size_t defined in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490622/where-is-c-size-t-defined-in-linux)" gives `long unsigned int`

### For C

(The question was originally tagged both C and C++.)

have a look at the answers here:

[What's sizeof(size_t) on 32-bit vs the various 64-bit data models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918787/whats-sizeofsize-t-on-32-bit-vs-the-various-64-bit-data-models)

Comment: Not all unsigned integers are `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely *no warranty* that `size_t` is defined as any "concrete" type. Actually, if you want to see a system where it's not `unsigned int`, see, for instance, my machine (`unsigned long`), and thus most 64-bit GNU/Linux systems.

From N4296, section 18.2.6:

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size bytes of any object.

Also, from N897 (Rationale) 6.5.3.4...

> The type of `sizeof`, whatever it is, is published (in the library
>   header `<stddef.h>`) as `size_t`, since it is useful for the programmer
>   to be able to refer to this type.  This requirement implicitly
>   restricts `size_t` to be a synonym for an existing unsigned integer
>   type. Note also that, although `size_t` is an unsigned type, `sizeof` 
>   does not involve any arithmetic operations or conversions that would
>   result in modulus behavior if the size is too large to represent as a 
>   `size_t`, thus quashing any notion that the largest declarable
>   object might be too big to span even with an `unsigned long` in C89 or 
>   `uintmax_t` in C9X. This also restricts the maximum number of elements
>   that may be declared in an array, since for any array `a` of `N`
>   elements,
>
> `N == sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`
>
> Thus `size_t` is also a convenient type for array sizes, and is so used in several library functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is unsigned integer type (not `unsigned int`). From [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> std::size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof
>   operator

But you can't say exactly what its size is, that I guess depends on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

From the [sys/types.h man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) :

> size_t shall be an unsigned integer type.

So at least theoretically it could be an unsigned `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `size_t` can and does differ from `unsigned int`.

Per the [C standard, 6.5.3.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in
>   `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

Under the C standard, `size_t` is an undefined unsigned integer type.

Per the [Open Group (POSIX, etc)](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html):

> **64-bit and Data Size Neutrality**
>
> ...
>
> *sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) =
>   sizeof(size_t)*

Simply put:

`size_t` **is** `size_t`.  Code that fails to conform to that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No. I just ran this program on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) which is gcc:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(unsigned int) << " " << sizeof(unsigned long) << " " << sizeof(size_t) << "\n";
}
```

and it produce this output:

4 8 8